# Swift how do I send AT commands to OBD2 device?

Tags: swift, obd-ii

I already know how to establish a wifi connection with the OBD2 adapter, but I have no idea how to request information from it. Like 010C is the command to return the engine RPM in hex form, but how do I even send "010C" to the OBD2 adapter? I can find answers and even OBD frameworks for languages like Java and Python, but nothing for swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already established a socket communication to the WiFi adapter, then either bind the socket to a pair of `NSStream`s and send/receive data using those or use the `CoreFoundation` API or the low-level `posix` API to send/receive data.

Chances are you might want something more high-level though. I have created an OBD2 library for iOS and macOS at https://github.com/mickeyl/LTSupportAutomotive. It's written in Objective-C and would need Swift bridging headers to make it useful for you, but that might be a good way for you to dive more into the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Our java implementation requires converting String messages, like "010C" or "ATZ" to byte[] and then sending those bytes to the OBD2 adapter. I imagine you'll have to do the same for swift.

Here is a resource on working with OBD2 adapters that may help you: http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to know OBD protocol such as: `ISO 9141-2`, `KW-2000`, `ISO 14230-4`, `SAE J1850` and `CAN ISO 15765-4` (11 bit or 29bit).

Take a look at this [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELM327) to get more information.

You can find `PID OBD2` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs).